# Run live website to localhost - magento 1.9.1.3

Tags: php, magento, localhost

I have some issues with running live website on Magento 1.9.1.3 to localhost.

So far as it goes I did this:

1. Exported the database from live hosting to a simple zipped file
   named localhost.sql.zip
2. Then import that database to my localhost/phpmyadmin using the import tool
3. The database(magen54) is imported and it is displayed in the database list
4. I put the unzipped files of Magento 1.9.1.3 in the C:/wamp64/www
5. I delete the local.xml file located in C:/wamp64/www/magento/app/etc
6. Re-index the core_config_data file to point to the localhost(127.0.0.1/magento/index.php)
7. I installed Magento using the magen54 database downloaded from the live hosting
8. Flushed Magento cash and re-index data from the admin panel**

   Nothing happened, it just stays to the default Magento page after the installation. 
   What i'm doing wrong ? Any ideas?

   Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you set the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` environment variables on the server/VirtualHost? Also, you probably didn't want to delete local.xml, just edit it with the correct variables (e.g. database user/password) for your local environment.

Comment: As an aside though - that's a really old (defunct) version of Magento. Magento 1.x is going completely out of support at the end of June as well.

Comment: CD001 - sorry dude, in the firm I'm working the website is running at Magento 1.x and I just want to try the migration on localhost first before I apply to live one. Anyway thank you buddy, can you explain how to find this MAGE_RUN_CODE and MAGE_RUN_TYPE, are they in the phpmyadmin ?

Comment: `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` are server [environment variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html) - if you've configured a `<VirtualHost>` in your local Apache *httpd-vhosts.conf* you'd set them in that with something like `SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE base` - there's also a chance they've already been set in the root *.htaccess* file if you copied that from the server.

Answer (score 0):

- I delete the local.xml file located in C:/wamp64/www/magento/app/etc

Why would you delete this?

You need this file, it needs updated with the database info/credentials for your local MySQL setup.